# jQuery slideUp() and slideDown() functions are firing at odd times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've provided a fiddle with the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/uLkx45aL/2/

```
$('.contact-social a').click(function() {
    $('.contact-social a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var className = $('.contact-social a.active').attr('className');
    $('.contact-wrap .content').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $('.contact-wrap .'+className).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

The above is the jQuery that I've used, and the general idea is that when a user clicks on of the icons along the bottom, then the current form/div slides up, and the one they selected scrolls down.

However currently it slides down twice before becoming fixed so I'm assuming there is an error in the jQuery but I can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Doesn't happen with the Facebook one for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sliding all the `.content` elements up. To resolve the issue you are seeing, you could use the [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) in order to select the visible `.content` element, and then slide it up:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ste4e3xn/)

```
$('.contact-social a').click(function () {
    $('.contact-social a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var className = $('.contact-social a.active').attr('className');
    $('.contact-wrap .content:visible').slideUp('fast', function () {
        $('.contact-wrap .' + className).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```